# Anki: Color cards by tag?

Tags: anki

I know how to change the background color of all cards in an Anki deck.

What I want to do, however, is to color the cards *with a given tag* differently from the rest.

Does anyone know how one could do this?

Of course, the ideal would be if the color of the card responded automatically to whether it had that tag or not: toggling the tag on the card would simultaneously toggle the card's color.

If this is not possible, the next best thing would be a convenient way to manually change the background color only for those cards that currently have a given tag.  I can filter the deck for such cards, but I don't know how to apply a background color change to only those cards.